# How to display a text file in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm new around here even though I am have been looking at these forums for ages and I finally need a bit of help;
I have tried this;

```
FileResource file = new FileResource(new File("/a/d/r/e/s/s/file"));
TextArea text = new TextArea();
text.setValue(file);
```

This;

```
FileResource file = new FileResource(new File("/a/d/r/e/s/s/file"));
TextArea text = new TextArea();
text.setValue(file.toString());
```

And;

```
FileResource file = new FileResource(new File("/a/d/r/e/s/s/file"));
TextArea text = new TextArea();
text.setValue(file.getAbosoluteFile().toString());
```

And others which are to big to show;

How do I show the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because this questioned is about filling a Vaadin component and not just a string.

Comment: Hi @WillPierlot if any of the answers has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the `TextFileProperty`:

```
TextArea text = new TextArea(new TextFileProperty(new File("/a/d/r/e/s/s/file")));
```

or the longer form:

```
TextArea text = new TextArea();
text.setPropertyDataSource(new TextFileProperty(new File("/a/d/r/e/s/s/file")));
```

What this piece of code does is it binds your Field TextArea to a Property. This is Vaadin's data binding mechanism. Property and Field synchronize each other automatically.

If you just want to display the file without editing it, consider using a Vaadin Label instead of the TextArea.

Comment: Sadly TextFileProperty (and properties in general) seems to be removed from Vaadin 8. Is there an easy to use alternative that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
 final TextArea textField = new TextArea();
 textField.setSizeFull();
 this.addComponent(textField);
 try {
     final File file = new File("/path/to/file");
     final String fileAsString = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
     textField.setValue(fileAsString);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

You will need to have the IO component from Apache Commons available to be able to import FileUtils

Comment: You could add the relevant package names, either directly or as `import` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Using the java standard library + java 8 streams

```
TextArea text = new TextArea();
String value = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file)).stream().collect(Collectors.joining())
text.setValue(value);
```

In Java 7 you can use the readAllLines function iterating over the List generated, in case that the size of the file is really big,follow a different approach, as the one that is explained here http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file